# Using the bootstrap form with $_GET method on same page

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, get

Im having trouble getting my form code to work, i want it to when they submit it to change the current page url, ex: weaw.com?id=Summitedtext and i am echoing it out from php.

```
        $cmd = 'htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])'
        echo '<form id="idform" action="' . $cmd . '" method="GET">';
        echo '<label><center>To search an inventory please put the users Profile URL in the input box below.</center></label>';
        echo '<div class="input-group">';
        echo '<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>';
        echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Profile URL" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">';
        echo '<span class="input-group-btn">';
        echo '<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">Go!</button>';
        echo '</span>';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';
```

Comment: horrible explain. Could you edit your question with further description?

Comment: @HosseinShahsahebi Ok i did so

Answer (score 0):

Totally disagree with echoing form but change your code to this and add your ingredients such class and so on:

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_GET['url'])
    $cmd = htmlspecialchars($_GET['url']);
else
    $cmd = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
?>
<form id="idform" action="<?PHP echo $cmd; ?>" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="url">
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```